# Is it possible to share someone's screen by only copying the DOM, JS, and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen

Is it possible to essentially share someone's screen by first copying the HTML, JS, CSS, and anything else relevant then pushing all this to the viewer's screen?  I'm thinking of an implementation where I inject my JavaScript into a page that I want to share, open a Websocket to my server, and attach events to the DOM to record changes to the DOM to push through the socket.  Are there any performance complications with this methodology?

Comment: By "screen" do you mean the entire screen or just someone else's view of a web page?

Comment: sounds shady and suspicious to me ?

Comment: Not to sure if this is related, but [**TeamViewer**](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) allows for sharing of desktop applications (browsers included) among those that you choose for online  collaboration.

Comment: please define "sharing". what stops you from letting the viewer to simply visit the original web site?

Comment: One issue (assuming by 'screen' you mean web browser view) is that the page could contain resources such as scripts, iframes and images, that the 2nd user does not have access to. Especially iframes would pose a problem because as far as I know, a script injected into the main page would not be able to access any of the content inside an iframe.

Comment: wow, thanks for the response! we mean a section of the page. no, this is not for shady purposes. it's to facilitate interaction and communication between multiple consenting parties. sharing means letting someone else see what i'm typing and highlighting on the page in real-time.

Comment: While performance might be an issue (I don't really know), I'd be more concerned about getting access to the user's selection and highlighting (of text, and inside forms). I think that'd be one challenging part.

Comment: Hi @Crashalot, Have you got any best way to achieve screen sharing ?. Please tell It will be helpful for us begineer.